# Notification with Firebase Database UI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, notifications, firebaseui

Is there any way to show a notification when data is added to Database with Firebase database UI. I tried it with notification Service (Offline) but it will also trigger on `onCreate()`.

Comment: Show the code you are attempting.

Comment: Have you considering using [Firebase Cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) to perform a task when trigged by an event in the database? [Notify users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) is an interesting read and can be found in the Firebase website documentation.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I check if there are changes under "users":

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(this);
```

The important thing is addValueEventListener. It is called each time there is a change under "users".

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext())
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
        .setContentTitle("My notification")
        .setContentText("Hello World!");
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(001, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And in this method I create the notification.

Comment: But is also called when we delete or modify the database.